# CV: should I make my email a hyperlink?

Tags: resume

*I am composing a CV. This question is about the email address field.*

Should I make my email address a hyperlink, pointing at `mailto:my@email.address`?

Note: My CV is to be in PDF format.

Comment: I would be surprised if hiring managers took this into account one way or the other.

Comment: @Adam V, I expect them to be either (1) delighted by the ease to click the link and request more information or (2) irritated by the blue underlined font.

Comment: My point is that it's not something to be either delighted or irritated about.

Comment: Definitly one for the "over-thinking" tag that some one needs to create :-)

Comment: Hi Vorac, this seems hard to answer without knowing why you're asking. Why do you think this wouldn't be a good idea to put this in your CV? I ask because I'm hoping the answers would be more helpful to you if we know the motivations. Can you expand your post a bit? Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

While I don't think it's a huge deal either way, I think the answer is generally "no" - don't using mailto formatting in your CV.

If the reviewer is looking at your CV online, they almost certainly know how to email you without requiring a mailto link.

And if the reviewer is reading your CV after it has been printed, the formatting may get in the way.

Comment: More over if their document reader is not setup to use their mail client, you will lose out the opportunity to be contacted by a weird head working for a really great firm.